# Puppeter not using the specified chrome-profile

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I put that command in windows bash shell to launch chrome with a specified chrome-profile

`start chrome --remote-debugging-port="${browserId}" --profile-directory="${task.profile}"`

Next: I launch puppeteer and try to connect to an existing browser, puppeteer opens up two browser windows. The first has the specified chrome-profile but then the second has the default profile and that is where all automation task is done. How can I make sure puppeteer uses the first window with the specified chrome-profile

`` const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL: `http://127.0.0.1:${task.browser}`, defaultViewport:null}) ``

Answer (score 3):

If it is not a must to launch chrome from bash, but it is OK to launch by the Node script itself then you could try the following. (In my example I used [websocket endpoint](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions) to connect to instead of `browserUrl`, feel free to choose which suits better your needs.)

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
  headless: true, 
  args: [
    `--user-data-dir=${task.profile}`
  ]
})
const browserWSEndpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint()
const browser2 = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint, defaultViewport: null })
```

*Note:* Make sure your `--user-data-dir` is correct. If you are on Windows you will need something like: `'--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\ProfileName'`

To determine the user data directory for a running Chrome instance:

> 1. Navigate to `chrome://version`
> 2. Look for the `Profile Path` field. This gives the path to the profile directory.
> 3. The user data directory is the parent of the profile directory.
>
> Example (Windows):
>
> - [Profile Path] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
> - [User Data Dir] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
>
> [[source]](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3202.58/docs/user_data_dir.md#current-location)

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. Turns out the code I inherited included default args were sent to puppeteer. These default args already a default user-data-dir in that points to the temp folder, which came first so Chrome was using the temp dir even though I was specifying something different. I couldn't change the defaults around so the fix I found was to use userDataDir direct with  puppeteer.launch, which takes precedence over the args. Using chrome://version was very useful debugging which profile directory is being used.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution: First I connect to the existing browser
`const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL:http://127.0.0.1:port, defaultViewport:null})`
And then I called: `const page = await browser.newPage()`
This is the point where two browser windows are open. So what I did was after connecting to the existing browser. I got all open pages `let pages = await browser.pages()` and then selected the first page `let page = pages[0]` so now puppeteer uses the first browser window with the selected profile. What I don't get is why does `const page = await browser.newPage()` open a new browser window instead of a new page in the same browser window. So this is what the solution looks like:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL: http://127.0.0.1:${task.browser}, defaultViewport:null})

let pages = await browser.pages()

let page = pages[0]

await page.goto(url)
```